# Value in an Output where it shouldn't be

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, if-statement

I am trying to condition this output so that each string is printed and formatted equally with the exception of "sarah". I've got this to work with the wording of her output being unique as she has only 1 "favourite language". However, now her language "C" is also in Jen's favourite language list when it shouldn't be. I tried using an `elif/else` in place of the 2nd `if` and got an `invalid syntax error`. I don't know how this is happening, thanks.

```
favourite_languages = {
    "jen": ["python", "ruby"],
    "sarah": ["c"],
    "edward": ["ruby", "go"],
    "phil": ["python", "haskell"],
    }
    for name, languages in favourite_languages.items():
    if len(languages) != 1:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite languages are:")
    for language in languages:
        print(f"\t{language.title()}")
    if len(languages) == 1:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite language is:")
        print(f"\t{language.title()}")
```

output:

```
Jen's favourite languages are:
    Python
    Ruby
    C

Sarah's favourite language is:
    C

Edward's favourite languages are:
    Ruby
    Go

Phil's favourite languages are:
    Python
    Haskell
```

Comment: which line and to what degree would I change indentation wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the condition `if len(languages) == 1` first. You can then use an `else` statement for the others. Also, when `len(languages) == 1`, you get the language name with `languages[0]` rather than `language`

```
for name, languages in favourite_languages.items():
    if len(languages) == 1:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite language is:")
        print(f"\t{languages[0].title()}")
    else:
         print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite languages are:")
         for language in languages:
             print(f"\t{language.title()}")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
suffix = "language is" if len(languages) == 1 else "languages are"
print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite {suffix}:")
```

The only difference between one language and multiple languages is a bit of text.  You shouldn't create a whole new section of code for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's due to incorect "for" loop :

```
favourite_languages = {
    "jen": ["python", "ruby"],
    "sarah": ["c"],
    "edward": ["ruby", "go"],
    "phil": ["python", "haskell"],
    }
for name, languages in favourite_languages.items():
    if len(languages) != 1:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite languages are:")
        for language in languages:
            print(f"\t{language.title()}")
    else:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite language is:")
        for language in languages:
            print(f"\t{language.title()}")
```

output :

```
Jen's favourite languages are:
    Python
    Ruby

Sarah's favourite language is:
    C

Edward's favourite languages are:
    Ruby
    Go

Phil's favourite languages are:
    Python
    Haskell
```